# Can't connect to Oracle 11g XE because listener does not currently know of SID

Tags: oracle

I tried to connect to Oracle 11g but this is what happens, and not for the first time.

> Listener refused the connection with the following error:
>   ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor Vendor code 12505.

Here is **listener.ora**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =

      (SID_LIST =
        (SID_DESC =
          (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
          (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
          (PROGRAM = extproc)
        )
        (SID_DESC =
          (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
          (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
          (PROGRAM = extproc)
        )
      )

    LISTENER =
      (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
        (DESCRIPTION =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-EJG24HE)(PORT = 1521))
        )
      )

    DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

and **tnsnames.ora**

```
    XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-EJG24HE)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

I tried to do something with it, but I cannot understand where is the problem.

Additional information:

```
SQL>  show parameter service_names
SP2-0640: Not connected

SQL> show parameter local_listener
SP2-0640: Not connected

SQL> alter system set LOCAL_LISTENER='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DESKTOP-EJG24HE)(PORT=1521))' scope=both;
SP2-0640: Not connected

SQL> alter system register;
SP2-0640: Not connected

SQL> connect as sysdba
Enter user-name: sys
Enter password:
Connected to an idle instance.
```

I tried to check status  of listener and other, but it is not like in my friend's program where it works right.

```
C:\Users\Sultankhan>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 24-╨б╙Ш╨г-2018 13:44:46

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                22-╨б╙Ш╨г-2018 00:56:00
Uptime                    2 days 12 hr. 48 min. 45 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-EJG24HE\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-EJG24HE)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

C:\Users\Sultankhan>netstat -an -O | find /i "1521"

  TCP    0.0.0.0:1521           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2772
  TCP    [::]:1521              [::]:0                 LISTENING       2772

C:\Users\Sultankhan>tnsping xe

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 24-╨б╙Ш╨г-2018 13:35:00

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-EJG24HE)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
OK (0 msec)
```

Comment: What command are you using to connect? Your tnsnames.ora entry uses service name not SID (correctly), so you don't seem to be using that alias to connect.

Comment: I use SQL Developer using SID. I tried to use service name but it doesn't work too

Comment: You should be using service name of XE rather than SID. But it looks like your database is not running. Check and start the database service on your PC.

Comment: OK. I tried to connect to Service name XE, then it gives this: Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Comment: Yes, because the database isn't running. Or at least isn't registered with the listener, but the "connected to idle instance" implies the DB isn't running at all - assuming your environment is set up consistently.

Comment: I also restarted database by clicking on Window -> Oracle Database 11g ->  Stop Database. Then after stopping it I clicked Start Databe and it was successful